# Edit CV shows icon / link as opening in new window but really doesn't

Tags: discussion, bug

When you go to edit your profile there is a new link to **Edit CV**.
The link indicates the page will open separately, but doesn't.  Either open target=_blank or don't bother with the icon:

[image]

Comment: Your caret looks like a carrot

Comment: Why look at that...you're right!  Totally unexpected

Comment: I'm disappointed there are no hand drawn red circles.